# mySql query - subtract resulted value

Tags: mysql, sql

I need a bit of help on a **mathematical function**,

Following query will result 2 lines per `lot` like this:

```
group | style | lot | section | q1 | q2 |q3  | q4  | ...

aaaaa | sssss | 123 | 111111  | 55 | 77 | 88 | 99 | ...

aaaaa | sssss | 123 | 222222  | 10 | 20 | 20 | 10 | ...

aaaaa | sssss | 321 | 111111  | 11 | 22 | 44 | 55 | ...

aaaaa | sssss | 321 | 222222  | 10 | 23 |33  | 10  | ...
```

each `lot` result 2 diff `section code`  (2 lines)

**Question is** :   how do I make a subtraction between the 2 `section code` for the colums q1 q2 q3 q4 q5 ... ?

**expected results:**

```
group | style | lot | q1 | q2 |q3 | q4  | ...

aaaaa | sssss | 123 | 45 | 57 |68 | 89 | ...

aaaaa | sssss | 321 | 1  | -1 |11 | 45 | ...
```

**query so far** :

```
SELECT DISTINCT gp_style_gr.code_groupe, po_lot.num_style, po_lot_sp.Num_lot,
po_lot_sp.num_secti, po_lot_se.code_secti, po_lot.terminer, po_lot.date_livraison,
po_lot_sp.qte_1, po_lot_sp.qte_2, po_lot_sp.qte_3, po_lot_sp.qte_4, po_lot_sp.qte_5,
po_lot_sp.qte_6, po_lot_sp.qte_7, po_lot_sp.qte_8, po_lot_sp.qte_9, po_lot_sp.qte_10,
po_lot_sp.qte_11, po_lot_sp.qte_12, po_lot_sp.qte_13, po_lot_sp.qte_14, po_lot_sp.qte_15,
po_lot_sp.qte_16, po_lot_sp.qte_17, po_lot_sp.qte_18, po_lot_sp.qte_19, po_lot_sp.qte_20,
po_lot_sp.qte_21, po_lot_sp.qte_22, po_lot_sp.qte_23, po_lot_sp.qte_24, po_lot_sp.qte_25,
po_lot_sp.qte_26, po_lot_sp.qte_27, po_lot_sp.qte_28, po_lot_sp.qte_29, po_lot_sp.qte_30

FROM po_lot_sp

LEFT OUTER JOIN po_lot_se ON po_lot_se.num_lot = po_lot_sp.num_lot 
and po_lot_se.num_secti = po_lot_sp.num_secti

LEFT OUTER JOIN po_lot ON po_lot.num_lot = po_lot_sp.num_lot

LEFT OUTER JOIN gp_style_gr ON gp_style_gr.num_style = po_lot.num_style

WHERE
((gp_style_gr.code_groupe = 'INSTOCK') and (po_lot.terminer = '0') 
and (po_lot_se.code_secti = '01')) or ((gp_style_gr.code_groupe = 'INSTOCK') 
and (po_lot.terminer = '0') and (po_lot_se.code_secti = '09'))

ORDER BY gp_style_gr.code_groupe, po_lot.num_style, po_lot_sp.Num_lot, 
po_lot_sp.num_secti, po_lot_se.code_secti, po_lot.terminer, po_lot.date_livraison,
```

Thanks !

Comment: How do you know which section to subtract from?

Comment: it will be always the same patern,  (2nd line - 1st line = what I want)

Comment: Your example shows 1st line - 2nd line, but regardless the solution by Andy Jones is the best one (with my amendment to the where clause).

Comment: oups you are right .. sorry just pass the last 16 hours in front of the screen, I will take a break I think

Answer (score 2):

If the section code follows some pattern as it does in your example, then you can simply join the table against itself.

I'll pretend your table is called `po_lot_sp` as it is in your example.

In the following query, I assume that the second row has a higher section number. That's the condition `t1.section > t2.section`. If not, change appropriately. If the section numbers follow no pattern, then ignore this completely.

```
SELECT t1.`group`, t1.style, t1.lot, t1.section,
  t2.q1 - t1.q1 q1, t2.q2 - t1.q2 q2, t2.q3 - t1.q3 q3, t2.q4 - t1.q4 q4
FROM t t1
JOIN t t2 ON t1.`group` = t2.`group` AND t1.style = t2.style AND
  t1.lot = t2.lot AND t1.section > t2.section
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d83017/1).

Comment: You need to add an additional where clause: " AND t1.lot = t2.lot"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select a.group,a.style,a.lot, 
coalesce(a.q1 - 
(select b.q1 from  tablename b where b.ID = a.ID + 1), a.q1) as q1,  
coalesce(a.q2- 
(select b.q2 from  tablename b where b.ID = a.ID + 1), a.q2) as q2,
coalesce(a.q3- 
(select b.q3 from  tablename b where b.ID = a.ID + 1), a.q3) as q3,
coalesce(a.q4- 
(select b.q4 from  tablename b where b.ID = a.ID + 1), a.q4) as q4
from tablename a group by a.lot
```

**Note:** Here `ID` refers to a primary key from your table and `tablename` refers to your original table name.So replace the field `ID` with your primary key field and table name vice-versa.

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/346f9/4)

Answer (score 0):

This is the fastest way I can think of. Of course, this is assuming that you want to decrement from section with value '111111':

```
SELECT `group`, style, lot,
  sum(if(section = '111111', q1, -q1)),
  sum(if(section = '111111', q2, -q2)),
  sum(if(section = '111111', q3, -q3)),
  sum(if(section = '111111', q4, -q4))
FROM t
GROUP BY `group`, style, lot
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/20b0e/1).

By the way, try not to use `group` as a column name. It is a reserved word.

If you don't know the section value you want to decrement from and you only want to decrement from the lowest section, then go for Andy's solution.

Comment: should I use my query to create a new table and then run another query (1st one that you posted is working fine)? or I can run it as a subquery?

Comment: I might not be getting the question. You can run it the way you want: in a subquery or just as it is. You don't need to create any table.

Comment: ok sorry, I'm new at this, just need to figure out how to do the syntax in all this .. cheers

Comment: humm.. I manage to make it almost work.. I've created a temp_table from my query results and then I run your scripts but the results are negative..  ex   10-3 = -13  instead of 10-3 = 7 ... something I do wrong?